# Angular pagination to array

Tags: angular, pagination, angular-material

How can I use angular pagination with array? This is what I tried and this is not working

.html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of array">
    {{item}}
</div>
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
```

.ts

```
array: any = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']

@ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
ngOnInit() {
        this.array.paginator = this.paginator
    }
```

and this screenshot is result, looks like there is no data in pagination source with showing "0 of 0"

[image]

How can I implement pagination to this array?
Please help me, thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59399019/how-do-i-paginate-cards-in-angular/59399358#59399358

Comment: @Eliseo Thanks, pagination is working but one question, how can I use pageSizeOption here? I can see page size is dynamic from .ts file but I'd like to manage this page size in frontend, from this one from above screenshot of result "Items per page (5,20,50,100)"

Comment: ::glups:: when edit the answer, forget add `[pageSize]="pageSize"` -just corrected in answer and in stackblitz

Comment: How do you use `this.array.paginator`? array has no paginator

Answer (score 0):

If its synchronous data, then you are able to use `<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]" [length]="array.length"></mat-paginator>`
If you fetching data from your BE then BE has to return something like:

```
{
  data:[1,2,3,4,5],
  _paging: {
     page:1,
     perPage:5,
     total:15
   }
}
```

then save total somehow and use it in paginator length

Answer (score 0):

Adding some points to above answer I think he missed some point `mat-paginator` also has `pageSize` option so it should be something like...

```
<mat-paginator  #paginator [pageSize]="10" [length]="array.length" [pageSizeOptions]="[2, 10, 20, 50, 100]">
```