# Angular material pagination not working correct

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a component that displays a large number of cards and I decided to do pagination using angular material, but I do not display the required number of cards and pagination does not work at all

this is a component of card rendering

**news-item.component.html**

```html
<section class="news-item">
  <div class="news-item__inner">
    <div *ngFor="let dataItem of dataItems; trackBy: trackByFn" class="news-item__item">
      <img src="{{ dataItem.image }}" alt="" class="news-item__img">
      <div class="news-item__content">
        <div class="news-item__title">{{ dataItem.title }}</div>
        <div class="news-item__description">
          <div class="news-item__text">{{ dataItem.description }}
          </div>
          <div class="news-item__button-wrapper">
            <button class="news-item__button">View</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="news-item__tags-wrapper">
          <ul class="news-item__tags">
            <li class="news-item__tag blue">{{ dataItem.groupMetal }}</li>
            <li class="news-item__tag">{{ dataItem.newsAgency }}</li>
            <li class="news-item__tag">{{ dataItem.date }}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**market-news.component.html**

```html
<section class="market-news">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="market-news__inner">
      <div class="market-news__title">Market News</div>
      <div class="market-news__input-filter-wrapper">
        <label class="market-news__input-label">Filter By</label>
        <input placeholder="Select a filter" type="text" class="market-news__input-filter">
      </div>
    </div>
    <app-news-item></app-news-item>
    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
  </div>
</section>
```

**market-news.component.ts**

```
export class MarketNewsPageComponent implements OnInit {
  public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<NewsItemComponent>();
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
}
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work, please help

Comment: What's `dataItems `?

Comment: @MicheleDaRin It's a data for cards

Comment: Your paginator is the paginator of a MatTableDataSource, but you iterate over dataItems. You can use a paginator to control an Array using slice pipe, like this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59399019/how-do-i-paginate-cards-in-angular/59399358#59399358)